# How to index a cell from a matrix in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find out how to choose the right diameter and number of rebars to the desired Area. I can find the right value from the Matrix using the MIN(IF(C9:L17>C9,L17:B6)) function or the SMALL(IF(C9:L17>C9,L17:B6),1), but can't index it to it's corresponding diameter and Number of rebar. The answer can be seperate with just the diameter or the Number of rebar but if it is possible I would like to have the answer like this format [Number of Rebar]Ø[Diameter].

As a second question. With the function SMALL i can find the second or third nearest value to my desired area. If the Diameter too small the function should choose the bigger Diameter. How can I impliment this idea to the whole function with index?

Example:
from a desired area of 7,8 cm2 [C3] there is 7,85cm2 [L10] chosen and the final answer for it is 10Ø10 [Number of Rebar]Ø[Diameter]

[image: Table for the rebar area]

Comment: Why are you referencing B6:L17 when your table starts in C9? And why reference the range backwards?

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw this comment, I was just concentratet myself to your anwser. Yes you are right. The function has to be MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17) in order you to get the right answer from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value 7,8539 etc, is being looked up from the table, it will be an exact match, so you can use a formula like this to find the row:

```
=MIN(IF(C9:L17=J30,C8:L8))
```

and the column with

```
=MIN(IF(C9:L17=J30,B9:B17))
```

You can combine the two values in a text string.

```
=MIN(IF(C9:L17=J30,B9:B17)) & "Ø" & MIN(IF(C9:L17=J30,C8:L8))
```

Edit: you can use a helper cell to arrive at the lookup number, like the formula you use to arrive at the value in J30, or you can nest that formula.

So, if J30 has the formula `=MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17))`, then you can also use this all-in-one formula to find the row:

```
=MIN(IF(C9:L17=MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17)),C8:L8))
```

and for the column:

```
=MIN(IF(C9:L17=MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17)),B9:B17))
```

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: So the looked up value is in the Cell C3 and it is not each time exact match with the values in the table. So if I use your function and the looked up value is not an exact match then I get the answer (0Ø0). I need to use the fuctions Sumproduct, Match, and the function that I wrote in my first post MIN(IF(C9:L17>C9,L17:B6)) together in order to get the corresponding Rebar diameter and the number. But still I don't have any solution.

Comment: How do you arrive at the value in cell J30? The MIN formula doesn't look like it will provide that. I also asked you about that formula above, but you haven't bothered to respond. Why should I help you if you don't answer my questions??

Comment: I have added a formula that integrates your formula for J30. If that solves your problem, please mark the answer.

Comment: I think you missed one parenthesis at the end of the second IF function. With your formula I had error. Instead I used =MIN(IF(C9:L17=MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17)),C8:L8)) for row and the =MIN(IF(C9:L17=MIN(IF(C9:L17>C3,C9:L17)),B9:B17)) for column and it works, thanks!

Comment: You're right. The bracket went missing when I copy/pasted the nested min/if function. I corrected it in my answer. Glad it's working for you now and thanks for the feedback.